# who will throw exception in spring jdbc if any mistake occur in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Recently I had attended one of java interview and I am unable to answer this question:

- Who will throw the exception in spring JDBC if any mistake occurs in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is [DataAccessException](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html), check the hierarchy of the Exception

```
java.lang.Object
  extended by java.lang.Throwable
      extended by java.lang.Exception
          extended by java.lang.RuntimeException
              extended by org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException
                  extended by org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
```

Answer (score 1):

> Who will throw the exception in spring JDBC if any mistake occurs in the database?

Spring JDBC Framework

> What exception will be thrown?

All the exceptions thrown by the Spring JDBC Framework are subclasses of **DataAccessException** which is a type of RuntimeException.